# Monotouch setting the Application Bundle Version

Tags: xamarin.ios, version

I'm trying to set the Application version for my MonoTouch project, but it doesn't seem like I have found the right location.

I've tried setting the version to 2.0.0 under:

- the Solution>General>Main Settings>Version field
- the Project>General>Main Settings>Version field (which can inherit from the solution)
- the Info.plist>iOS Application Target>Version field

If I check the version using

```
 string currentVersion = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleVersion"].ToString();
```

I only ever get back 1.0 as the version.  Am I missing a place to set the application version, or do I need to use a different method for checking the BundleVersion?

Here is the version info I am running

```
MonoDevelop 3.0.5
Installation UUID: 554868b3-3202-4955-bf88-38a3e5949a79
Runtime:
Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)
GTK 2.24.10
GTK# (2.12.0.0)
Package version: 210090011
Apple Developer Tools:
 Xcode 4.5.1 (1842)
 Build 4G1004
Monotouch: 6.0.6 (Evaluation)
```

Comment: Changing the value of the `Info.plist` (like you mentioned, using **iOS Application Target**, **Version** field) to 2.0 works for me using the code you supplied. Can you edit your question to add all the version information (see MonoDevelop's About dialog to copy/paste them) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the same change in my own `Info.plist` file works perfectly with the code you provided, i.e. I do get the expected `2.0.0` string. I also tried it inside the iOS simulator since you're using the evaluation version.

I do have newer versions of the softwares - but they are not very different and I do not recall anything changed in those area.

Can you look (and maybe add it in your question) the content of your `Info.plist` ? it should be an XML file (default format used by MonoDevelop) and should have your `2.0.0` string inside it.

If that does not work please zip a small sample that do so and attach it to a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) as there might be something that does not, always, get updated ?!?

Comment: Tried doing yet another Clean followed by a Rebuild on the project. Then on my plist, I changed the Main Interface from iPhone to iPad and got a crash.  This removed my project from the recent projects list.  However, after all of that, the application version is now displaying correctly, and updates when I change it in the plist file.

Comment: @cain That's weird. If you have the old (original version) available (e.g. in source control) then it would be nice to have a look at them. This issue (and the crash) should not happen - but are likely difficult to reproduce without the files.

Comment: Sadly no old version of the old plist, but I can still get the crash when I play with the Main Interface. Submitted a bug report for that one, just now.  Since this question is likely not relevant to many other users, I will delete it shortly.  Thanks for your help.